# SQL Server 2008 Foreign Keys that are auto indexed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, relationship

Are Foreign Keys in SQL Server 2008 are automatically indexed with a value?   For Example. if I add a value in my Primary  key (or auto incremetend) in may parent table  will the table that has a foreign key  referenced to that key will automatically have the same value? or I Have to do it explicitly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, if you create a foreign key in a child table, it will not automatically get populated when a parent row gets inserted. If you think about this it makes sense. Let's say you have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Students
(
  StudentID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Name SYSNAME
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.StudentLoans
(
  LoanID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  StudentID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Students(StudentID),
  Amount BIGINT -- just being funny
);
```

What you are suggesting is that when you add a row to `Students`, the system should automatically add a row to `StudentLoans` - but what if that student doesn't have a loan? If the student does have a loan, what should the amount be? Should the system pick a random number?

Typically what will happen in this scenario is that you'll be adding a student and their loan at the same time. So if you know the loan amount and the student's name, you can say:

```
DECLARE 
  @Name       SYSNAME = N'user962206', 
  @LoanAmount BIGINT = 50000,
  @StudentID  INT;

INSERT dbo.Students(Name) 
  SELECT @Name;

SELECT @StudentID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT dbo.StudentLoans(StudentID, Amount)
  SELECT @StudentID, @LoanAmount;
```

Comment: Then How would I add a value to a foreign key that references the primary key in my child table ? for Example I added a student, how would I add the value of his/hers primary key to the student loans table knowing that he has a student loan?**EDITED** thanks! btw will that query work in LINQ To SQL?

Comment: Did you try the example? `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is one way to retrieve the auto-generated value from the `IDENTITY` column in the table most recently inserted. If you're doing this at two different times, then you need to find the PK for the student you're interested in (how are you identifying them?) and then use that value in subsequent insert statements.

Comment: I have not tried the SCOPE_IDENTITY it yet, is that query applicable in LINQ TO SQL?

Comment: Sorry, I have absolutely no idea, I don't use LINQ. Have you done research into this technology and come to a logical conclusion that you should use it? I suspect that if you are needing to learn about databases LINQ is probably not the best approach.

Comment: I see, though we are required to use LINQ, I think I need to refresh my memory with regards to Databases. But either way this has been a very huge helped. and I understand why the foreign keys in the other table shouldn't been incremented. Thank you @Aaron Bertrand